# Spark UDF not running in parallel

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm attempting to use the Python port of the Google `phonenumbers` library to normalize 50 Million phone numbers. I'm reading into a SparkDataFrame from a Parquet file on S3 and then running operations on the dataframe. The following function, `parsePhoneNumber`, is expressed as a UDF:

```
def isValidNumber(phoneNum):
    try:
        pn = phonenumbers.parse(phoneNum, "US")
    except:
        return False
    else:
        return phonenumbers.is_valid_number(pn) and phonenumbers.is_possible_number(pn)

def parsePhoneNumber(phoneNum):
    if isValidNumber(phoneNum):
        parsedNumber = phonenumbers.parse(phoneNum, "US")
        formattedNumber = phonenumbers.format_number(parsedNumber, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)

        return (True, parsedNumber.country_code, formattedNumber, parsedNumber.national_number, parsedNumber.extension)
    else:
        return (False, None, None, None)
```

And below is a sample of how I use the UDF to derive new columns:

```
newDataFrame = oldDataFrame.withColumn("new_column", parsePhoneNumber_udf(oldDataFrame.phone)).select("id", "new_column".national_number)
```

Executing the UDF by running `display(newDataFrame)` or `newDataFrame.show(5)` or something similar only uses one executer in the cluster, so it doesn't appear that something in the UDF is causing it only run on one worker.

If I'm doing anything that would prevent this from running in parallel, can you provide some insight?

The execution environment is on a cloud cluster controlled by Databricks.

Edit: Below is the output of `oldDataFrame.explain`

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Relation[id#621,person_id#622,phone#623,type#624,source_id#625,created_date#626,modified_date#627] parquet

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: string, person_id: string, phone: string, type: string, source_id: string, created_date: string, modified_date: string
Relation[id#621,person_id#622,phone#623,type#624,source_id#625,created_date#626,modified_date#627] parquet

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Relation[id#621,person_id#622,phone#623,type#624,source_id#625,created_date#626,modified_date#627] parquet

== Physical Plan ==
*FileScan parquet [id#621,person_id#622,phone#623,type#624,source_id#625,created_date#626,modified_date#627] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[dbfs:/mnt/person-data/parquet/phone], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,person_id:string,phone:string,type:string,source_id:string,created_date:strin...
```

Comment: How do you create SparkSession?

Comment: I don't believe it's necessary to build a SparkSession on Databricks; therefore, I'm using `sqlContext` directly.

Comment: Ok, but in which mode is your SparkSession  running? Maybe `local`, then it will run on one node

Comment: Please run `sc.master` where sc is SparkContext

Comment: Running `sc.master` returns a URL.

Answer (score 7):

You are all good. `Display`, with default arguments shows the first 1000 rows at most. Similarly `newDataFrame.show(5)` shows only the first five rows.

At the same time execution plain (`oldDataFrame.explain`) shows no shuffles so in both cases Spark will evaluate only the minimum number of partitions to get the required number of rows - for these values it is probably one partition.

If you want to be sure:

- Check if `oldDataFrame.rdd.getNumPartitions()` is larger than one.
- If it is, force execution of all partitions with `df.foreach(lambda _: None)` or `newDataFrame.foreach(lambda _: None)`.

You should see more active executors.

Comment: `show()` uses normal `limit` - it should do local limit and then global limit. Maybe Parquet file has only one partition?

Comment: I've been partitioning our CSV files into 25 when converting them to Parquet, so the output of `oldDataFrame.rdd.getNumPartitions()` is 25. In addition, running `oldDataFrame.foreach(lambda _: None)` executes 4 tasks each on the 4 workers.

To that point, is using `withColumn` the appropriate strategy here? I assume simply mapping over the DataFrame will execute in parallel as well.

Comment: @sean Spark gets more and more complicated, maybe they optimized this. So, up vote deserved ;)

Comment: @T.Gawęda As far as I remember `show(n)` will evaluate  to `df.limit(n).queryExecution...` and with narrow transformation (no shuffle) it will collect only as much as it needs.

Comment: @sean `withColumn` is fine. If you do `newDataFrame.foreach(lambda _: None)` you should parallel execution. Single task for `show`, mean that Spark can optimize, and do only as much work, as need.

Comment: @user8371915 Yes, you are right, that is why I upvoted your answer. I was wrong about it

Comment: @T.Gawęda The worst thing about having an optimizer is that you never know what exactly happens out there. And now we have cost based one :)